# Removing site meta description from Joomla 3 protostar template

Tags: joomla, social-networking, meta-tags

I have integrated a LinkedIn social share button to my Joomla 3 site.  When I go to share the page the share popup shows the phrase 'my Joomla CMS' beside the site title that is being shared.  Obviously I do not want this to show. There is some kind of meta description somewhere in the site files but I cannot figure out how to remove it.

I have tried the following:

- gone into global configuration and changed site meta description and keywords as well as set 'show meta' and 'show version' to no;
- added this line:

  ```
    <?php $this->setGenerator(null); ?>
  ```

  to the index.php file
- installed the byebyegenerator plugin
- commented out all generator code in the head.php and document.php files

After all of this, the linkedin share popup still shows 'my joomla cms' in the site title description.

How can I remove this from my site?

Comment: Which extension are you using on the Joomla Extensions Directory?  Please provide a like to the JED so I can download a copy of the plugin.

Comment: The plugin that was supposed to remove any meta description is here: http://bit.ly/1IKsrqQ     the actual social sharing code is the code provided by linkedin to share a page: http://linkd.in/1EW66CW